# Linux Mint Maya on Student Computers. How do I find the application name for Youtube?

Tags: linux, youtube

I have 12 student computers that are running Linux Maya. I have windows 7 with limited control over the student computers with LAN School. LAN School is not compatible with Linux, I am fully aware of this, but my IT department refuses to acknowledge defeat. I have been able to limp the software communications along. I need to find out how to obtain application names for programs students are running that need to be blocked. For example, I have youtube listed as a blocked website and application on LAN School, but the students can still get through. I believe if I have the correct application name of YouTube in linux I can block the use of the application from LAN School.

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I was curious about the software, so I looked it up.  You might not be aware, but the latest version supports Ubuntu, which means it should work with Mint.

Comment: Even with the update we are still running only Linux 13 which I believe is Maya and not true "Ubuntu" we still can not fully use the system. i.e. blocking websites and applications. LAN School staff has been very helpful and they only true fix is to have windows, but that will never happen. :( Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

It's called ["minitube"](http://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/minitube) on Linux Mint, but I'm not really sure that that is what you really need to know...

Hope that helps!

~Questionmark

Comment: Any input helps I'm desperate so I will try everything.

Answer (score 0):

From [LAN School's](http://www.lanschool.com/) current website they seem to support Linux.

Anyways, if you have access to the student's computers. Then simply set the correct UFW rules in the firewall of the root user. Also disable the ability to install new software for non-root (student) accounts.

Comment: The LAN School staff has been great they only support Ubuntu at this time which of course is what we don't have. Thanks for your help I will try this out!